# How to render breadcrumbs in component view and load breadcrumbs for menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, breadcrumbs

I have a problem rendering breadcrumbs in a custom component.

1) I need to **render breadcrumbs** in **my component** like this:

**home/menu_item_level_1/my_component_view_name**

But I don't know how to render breadcrumbs core component in my component.

or how to load breadcrumbs for menu "menu_item_level_1" (let's say it has id=1).

The problem is that the breadcrumbs module needs a menu item. But I can only create a menu item for a specific page like this /component/com_mycomponent/?id=1. I can't create a menu for a dynamic url like: /component/com_mycomponent/?id=$id

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Iguess I found decision BY MYSELF!

1) Add **.xml** file to view, that will match your **.php** file in view's layout.

Example: you have **com_competition\site\views\competition\tmpl\default.php**

Add default.xml in the same directory with code. The main thing to remember is that it's name should match with the name of your .php layout file.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_COMPETITION_COMPETITION_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>COM_COMPETITION_COMPETITION_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC</message>
    </layout>
    <fields
            name="request"
            addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_competition/models/fields"
            >
    </fields>
</metadata>`

2) Go to admin panel and add new menu item and choose your type link "COM_COMPETITION_COMPETITION_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE".

3) You can send $id this way in browser **home/your_menu_1/your_new_component_menu/?id=2**

So, follow this steps you will create SEF links and add breadcrumbs to your component. Cheers! Profit